# Trouble with using a special type in two header files. (C code)

Tags: c

I'm having trouble using a special type I made in two header files. One header files defines the type, the other one uses it in an extern variable, and a function.

```
"newtype.h"

typedef struct {
   double i, s;
} newtype_t;

newtype_t this(){}
newtype_t that(){}
```

Now I have another header with a variable and function:

```
"newfuncs.h"

extern newtype_t c;
newtype_t divide(double d, double e);
```

I'm getting:

```
unknown type name 'newtype_t' //inside of "newfuncs.h"
```

This new header "newfuncs.h" is an addition to already working code that utilizes the new type and functions from "newtype.h". 
I'm using this newtype_t inside of newfuncs.h.

I tried to #include "newtype.h" but I get a multitude of errors involving "conflicting types" in my .c files.

Comment: You probably missed `include "newtype.h"`

Comment: I don't see any `#include`s...

Comment: Unknown type name hints that the type itself was not declared at the reported line. Is your "newtype.h" file included before that line in your "newfuncs.h" file?

Comment: the #include "newtype.h" does not work; I'll add that in my orginal question.

Comment: Show *everything*.

Comment: Then there's an error somewhere in newtype.h. It's very purpose is just to declare types; if including it fails to do that, it's broken.

Comment: The obvious first problem: `this()` and `that()` should only be declared in the `.h` file. The inclusion of `{}` makes them actually defined, and you can only do that once. Defining functions should be done in a `.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

If a header use a type declared in another header, it should include it.

To prevent multiple declaration problem, you should add a guard in your header files:

```
// file newtype.h
#ifndef NEWTYPE_H // the guard
#define NEWTYPE_H

// all header stuff goes here
typedef int my_type;

#endif // end of guard
```

By doing this, each type or function will only be defined once. Each guard macro should be unique, you can use the file name to choose its name.

Some compiler (like cl) have a special comment to prevent multiple inclusion: `#pragma once`

Comment: Ah HAH! That's where I went wrong. When I first added the guards to newtype.h, I did not know the correct format. I thought it was "newtype.h" or just newtype.h, it has to be NEWTYPE_H (the underscore). Thank you for your time!!

Comment: `NEWTYPE_H` is just a common naming convention.  It can be named anything that's a valid identifier.  If your original version used `#ifndef newtype.h`, the problem was the period.  `#ifndef FOO` `#define FOO` would work just as well. (You *should* use `NEWTYPE_H`, but only because that makes it easy to remember what token is associated with each header.)

Answer (score 0):

did you included the header files in the right order?

I just tested it and it works

test.c

```
#include "newtype.h"
#include "newfuncs.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double d = 4.0;
    double e = 2.0;
    c = divide(d, e);
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
    printf("%lf", c.i);
    printf("%lf", c.s);
    return 0;
}

newtype_t divide(double d, double e){
    newtype_t x;
    x.i = d;
    x.s = e;
    return x;
}
```

newtype.h

```
#ifndef NEWTYPE_H
#define NEWTYPE_H
typedef struct {
   double i, s;
} newtype_t;

#endif
```

newfuncs.h

```
#ifndef NEWFUNCS_H
#define NEWFUNCS_H
newtype_t c;
newtype_t divide(double d, double e);

#endif
```

but even without the define it works for me (gcc 5.3.1).